# White space around the arcgis map when zoom value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a problem with maps that are built using JavaScript Library (React) I'm using the @arcgis/core module,
and when I change the zoom value to make the map cover all world that will show a white space,
Is there any way to remove it and make the map take a 100% size from the parent element?
Thank you all.
[enter image description here][1]

Here an example for  my case
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n8m1.jpg

And here is my initilizer.js file config

```
import ArcGISMap from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";
import SceneView from "@arcgis/core/views/SceneView";
import config from "@arcgis/core/config";

import "./style.css";
import { imagesLayer } from "../../utils/helper";

export const mapInitializer = (
    container,
    mapProperties,
    viewProperties,
    mapLayers,
    mapType
) => {
    config.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ARCGIS_API_KEY;
    const map = new ArcGISMap({
        ...mapProperties,
    });
    console.log({ mapLayers });
    map.addMany([imagesLayer, ...mapLayers]);

    const view =
        mapType === "3D"
            ? new SceneView({
                map,
                ...viewProperties,
            })
            : new MapView({
                map,
                ...viewProperties,
            });

    !view &&
        false.on("key-down", (event) => {
            const prohibitedKeys = ["+", "-", "Shift", "_", "="];
            const keyPressed = event.key;
            if (prohibitedKeys.indexOf(keyPressed) !== -1) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    view.on("mouse-wheel", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    view.on("double-click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    view.on("drag", ["Shift"], (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    view.on("drag", ["Shift", "Control"], (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    view.on("drag", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    view.container = container;
    view.ui.empty("top-left");
    view.ui._removeComponents(["attribution"]);

    view
        .when()
        .then((_) => {
            console.log("Map Initialized");
        })
        .catch(() => console.error("Map Initialization Error"));

    return null;
};
```

Comment: It is a resolution problem, the basemap usually are built 512x512, 96 dpi. At full extent in most monitors (high definition, large screens) it will look like that. Think it like this, you have an image and you want to display it in different frames sizes. So what you want to do?